# Allowing frontend JavaScript POST requests to https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token endpoint

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, cors, spotify

In order to get an access token for the Spotify API in my web app (as specified by their Web Authorization Flow), I've learned that I have to make a `POST` request. However, when I do so, I get the `XMLHttpRequest` `500 Error` due to the cross-origin problem.

I have already figured out how to allow CORS `GET` requests, but am not sure how to do the same for `POST` requests. [This link](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) provides configuration tips, but it leaves the actual routes for `GET` and `POST` blank.

This is the relevant code for my Express.js server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});



app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // looks in public directory, not root directory (protects files)

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.send(__dirname + '\\index.html')
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body.spotify);
});
```

(`spotify` is the `spotify-web-api-js` node module).

I've previously tried copying the exact code for `app.get` into `app.post`, but that caused the server to crash.

This is the bit of code in my program's JavaScript file that intends to send a `POST` request after the user clicks on a button that takes them to the start of Spotify's authorization path and approves the sign-in:

```
$('#spotify').on('click', function() {
    $.support.cors = true;

    $.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");

      });
```

(in this case, `spotify` is the ID for the button in the HTML file)

What should I do to bypass the CORS issue in this case? I've been stumped for a few days.

Comment: Your server cannot grant access (via CORS or otherwise) to Spotify's API on their behalf. Their application must itself respond with the necessary headers to permit the request. If it doesn't, the request may simply not be possible from the client. Side notes: There are existing packages for enabling CORS within Node HTTP applications, including [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Also, for all but the most basic of requests, a [preflight `OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) request may be sent ahead of them.

Comment: I already have the `cors` package installed, but I can't find any config settings for `POST` requests. I was able to get around the CORS access issue when sending `GET` requests for song/artist data. This is part of Spotify's web authentication flow according to their dev site and an employee here said that `POST` should be used, so it should technicaly be possible...

Comment: By doing it client-side, you're involving the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) on top of just HTTP, creating the requirement of CORS. Spotify can choose whether or not to enable CORS on individual paths and, it appears, they have chosen not to for `/api/token`. So, the way to accomplish it may very well be: Don't try to do it strictly client-side with Ajax. Use [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) within your server to make the actual request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find an example of using express to perform the authentication flow with Spotify on https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples (see the `authorization_code` approach).

You can't get an access token making a client-side request to `/api/token`. You need to make a request to `/authorize`, which will redirect to your `redirect_uri`, which itself will exchange a `code` with an access token.

Check that example, which should cover your needs.