# Client Credentials Flow works with curl but not in browser

Tags: javascript, curl, spotify

I am developing a Spotify application and I want to get the token.

I am following [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow) and using `curl` everything works fine:

```bash
$ curl -H "Authorization: Basic YjU4Y...llYTQ=" \
-d grant_type=client_credentials \
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
# Response:
# {
#   "access_token":"BQD3u...W4iJA",
#   "token_type":"Bearer",
#   "expires_in":3600
# }
```

And here, there is the Javascript code of my HTML file where I try to get the same result:

```js
var url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
var authentication = "YjU4Y...llYTQ=";
var params = { grant_type: "client_credentials" };
var auth = "Basic " + authentication;

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
      'Authorization' : auth,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  data: params,
  success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
  }
});
```

However, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there really a way to use the Spotify API from a static HTML file using Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188989/allowing-cors-jquery-post-requests-to-spotify-api-on-express-js-server/33198424#33198424 seems relevant. And https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples. And http://stackoverflow.com/users/540274/jos%C3%A9-m-p%C3%A9rez from Spotify seems to be around on SO answering questions.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker but I don't want any server side code.

Comment: If you are trying to authenticate from client side, why are you using client credentials which requires a server side application due to CORS instead of   implicit grant? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I concur, you're using the wrong oAuth 2.0 flow. Look up Implicit Grant.

Comment: Implicit Grant Flow needs a **redirect_uri** and I don't know what to put there if I don't have a server. Cc: @MichaelThelin

Comment: @marc_aragones did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the exact same issue you are - I control the server too. I've also tried it locally and via an AWS Lambda script. Every single attempt I receive "Bad Request" or a 400 error or even using the `passport-spotify` node module which just hangs with no response.

Comment: Sorry but no, @SMT

Comment: @marc_aragones i actually resolved my issue - the dotenv module where i hide environment variables was, for some reason, corrupting the client ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing.  Browsers disallow CORS unless the server specifically authorizes it.  In your case, you don't control the server so you have only one choice - hack the browser.  Easily done with plugins for Firefox and Chrome.  Search for CORS Everywhere for Firefox.  There one for chrome too called access control allow *, or something like that.

Trust me...  I spent a week trying a different REST api.  Tried js fetch, etc.  You must hack the browser with the plugin.

Comment: But what does Spotify want developers to do in these cases? Hacking the browser seams a temporary solution.

Comment: I can't speak to Spotify in particular.  I've never looked at it.  Look and see if they publish some API documentation.  Search "CORS".  That's your issue - CORS.